# What does it mean to have an ordered pair to the power of something?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing linear algebra, so there's this pair of ordered pairs:

$$(2,-1)^{-3} \circ \left(8,\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$

I don't understand what the ordered pair to the power of something means, at first i thought it'd be the cartesian product of itself but that doesn't make sense. Does it mean to take each element in the ordered pair and raise it by the power of $n$? where $n$ would be the power that the ordered pair is being raise to.

Here's how $\circ$ is defined:

$$(a,b) \circ (c,d) = (a+c+2,3bd)$$ in R x R*, also it's said to be an abelian group

Sorry for the extremely basic question.

Comment: More context might help. What is $\circ$? Is the text discussing a group perhaps, where the elements happen to be pairs and $\circ$ is the operator?

Comment: yes that's it, does it mean that raising it to the power of `n` means applying `o` n-times?

Comment: It's hard to say without a description of what $\circ$ does.

Comment: @Jose From what we know, this seems to be the best (or only) plausible explanation

Comment: With the definition of $\circ$, i could guess what $(a,b)^n$ for a positive $n$ is (I think it would be $n$-fold composition), but not fractional or negative. This is not a linear algebra question... it's a question of bad notation. Could we see the question in it's entirety? is $R = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Added the definition of $\circ$ but the negative exponential confuses me

Comment: One plausible idea, is that $(a,b)^n$ for $n$ negative, **could** be the unique inverse of  $(a,b)^{-n}$. Remember the identity of your group would be $(0,1)$ as the left entries form an abelian group under $+$ and the right with $\times$. Assuming $R \cong (\mathbb{R}, +) \times (\mathbb{R^*}, \cdot)$ as groups is the group you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way of interpreting this: Find the identity $e$ of this group.  That is, find $e$ such that for any ordered pair $(a, b)$,

$$
(a, b) \circ e = (a, b) = e \circ (a, b)
$$

In this case, $e = (x, y)$ will be a specific ordered pair.  Now, try to show that given any ordered pair $(a, b)$, you can find another ordered pair $(c, d)$ such that

$$
(a, b) \circ (c, d) = e = (c, d) \circ (a, b)
$$

In that case, $(c, d)$ can be treated as the inverse of $(a, b)$; that is,

$$
(c, d) = (a, b)^{-1}
$$

And then we might interpret $(a_1, b_1)^{-m} \circ (a_2, b_2)^n$ as

$$
[(a_1, b_1)^m]^{-1} \circ (a_2, b_2)^n
$$

which can be shown to be equal to

$$
[(a_1, b_1)^{-1}]^m \circ (a_2, b_2)^n
$$